# OnDraw method hides previous drawing

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am kinda new to android and I am creating a small app where I can draw rectangle and circle on custom view.

What I am trying to do is when **Circle** button is pressed I want to draw circle and when **Rectangle** button is pressed I want to draw a rectangle.

But the problem, I am having is when I press circle button it draws the circle correctly, but when I click on the rectangle button and tries to draw it, it hides the previous drawn circle and draws a rectangle. If again I select the circle, and draw it, it will hide the rectangle and draws a circle.

**MainActivity.java**: when button is pressed, buttonPressed method is called:

```
private DrawingView drawView;

public void buttonPressed(View v)
{
  String shape = v.getTag().toString();
  if(shape.equals("circle"))
  {         
    Log.e("button pressed", "circle");
    drawView.setValue("circle");            
  }
  else if(shape.equals("rect"))
  {
     Log.e("button pressed", "rect");
     drawView.setValue("rect");
  }     
}
```

and in my **DrawingView** class's onDraw method I am doing:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
{
  if(testValue.equals("rect"))
  {
     // draw rectangle
  }
  else if(testValue.equals("circle"))
  {
    // draw circle
  }
}

// setter method to set value
public void setValue(String val) 
{
  testValue = val;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Android Views will automatically clear their canvas before onDraw() is called, so you'll have to do one of two things:

1. Keep a list of items to draw, add to the list when a button is pressed, and iterate over it in onDraw(). This is simple to implement, but might slow down the draw process if your list gets long. This happens on the UI thread, so be careful.
2. Make your own Canvas from a private Bitmap matching the size of your View, and draw on it when a button is pressed. In onDraw(), use drawBitmap() to copy your buffer onto the View.